# How do I get this modal dialog to scroll on mobile?

Tags: css, polymer, dart-polymer

I have a modal dialog (overlay) that responsively fills the full width and height of the viewport on small screens. When there is a lot of vertical content, the mobile user needs to be able to scroll. I'm using Polymer's core-overlay.

See http://mycommunity.org and click Add Stuff, then make your browser window smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
::content #container {
   overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Looks like that did the trick! Specifically here for me:

@media all and (max-width: 600px)  {
  polyfill-next-selector { content: ':host #container'; }
  ::content #container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
}